# setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel) в PyQt6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt6, qmessagebox, standardbuttons

У меня два вопроса.

1. Не получается добавить кнопку в `setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel)`. Слово **`Cancel`** подсвечивается как ошибка и при нажатии кнопки `message`, программа закрывается.
2. И вторая проблема, когда нажимаю на кнопку '**`2`**', то получается что в окне `QLineEdit` можно напечатать только один раз цифру, т.е. хотел бы, чтобы сколько раз нажал на кнопку, столько цифра '**`2`**' и появилась. Как я понял надо делать это через цикл, но я не понял как.

---

```
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *

class Calc(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Calculator')
        self.resize(300, 300)

        self.one = QPushButton('message', self)
        self.one.move(100, 200)
        self.one.clicked.connect(self.mes)

        self.two = QPushButton('2', self)
        self.two.move(200, 200)
        self.two.clicked.connect(self.click)

        self.lne_edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lne_edit.move(50, 100)



    def click(self, num):
        self.lne_edit.setText(self.two.text())

    def mes(self):
        self.msg = QMessageBox(self)
        self.msg.setText('Привет')
        self.msg.setInformativeText('Другое сообщение')
        self.msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel)
        self.msg.exec()

        
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        Calc = Calc()
        Calc.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На счет QMessageBox разобрался. Надо было так сделать -> QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. 

- **PyQt5**:

  self.msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel)
- **PyQt6**:

  self.msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.StandardButtons.Cancel)

2. `self.lne_edit.setText(self.lne_edit.text() +  self.two.text())`

---

```
class Calc(QDialog): 
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.setWindowTitle('Calculator') 
        self.resize(300, 300)

        self.one = QPushButton('message', self)
        self.one.move(100, 200)
        self.one.clicked.connect(self.mes)

        self.two = QPushButton('2', self)
        self.two.move(200, 200)
        self.two.clicked.connect(self.click)

        self.lne_edit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lne_edit.move(50, 100)



    def click(self, num):
# -        self.lne_edit.setText(self.two.text())
        self.lne_edit.setText(self.lne_edit.text() +  self.two.text())        # !!!
        

    def mes(self):
        self.msg = QMessageBox(self)
        self.msg.setText('Привет')
        self.msg.setInformativeText('Другое сообщение')
# !!!        
#        self.msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel)                       # PyQt5
        self.msg.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.StandardButtons.Cancel)       # PyQt6   # !!!
        
        self.msg.exec()

    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Calc()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!!! Я вот на счет MessageBox уже разобрался, а вот на счет второго вопроса, ни где не мог найти инфы, в одном видео на ютубе совсем по другому было и в итоге ничего не получалось.

Comment: @Евгений пожалуйста.