# Не получается сделать всплывающие окно QMessageBox в PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqt6, qmessagebox, standardbuttons

Сейчас учу *PyQt* по этому курсу https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL0lO_mIqDDFXeDkOLHmEsL_HAEhw4-xDX . 
На 4 уроке мужик делает всплывающие окно при ошибке. У меня красным подчеркивало названия кнопок для этого окна. Я понял, что ошибка из-за разницы *PyQt5* (гайд) и *PyQt6*, с которым я работаю.

[setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Cancel) в PyQt6](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1400558/setstandardbuttonsqmessagebox-cancel-%D0%B2-pyqt6) По аналогии с этой ошибкой пытался исправить проблему, но всплывающие окно все равно не появляется.

Прошу, помогите. Заранее извиняюсь, за глупый вопрос, за непонятную формулировку и тд. Буду рад, если подробно объясните в чем не прав.

Вот метод, в котором я это пытаюсь сделать:

```
def results(self):
        if not self.is_equal:
            res = eval(self.label.text())
            self.label.setText("Результат: " + str(res))
            self.is_equal = True
        else:
            error = QMessageBox()
            error.setWindowTitle("ОШИБКА")
            error.setText("Сейчас это действие выполнить нельзя")
            error.setIcon(QMessageBox.setIcon(Warning))
            error.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok|QMessageBox.StandardButton.Cancel)

            error.exec_()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Просто при выполнения действия из за которого, должно появляться всплывающие окно, оно не появляется

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
    ...
            error = QMessageBox()
            error.setWindowTitle("ОШИБКА")
            error.setText("Сейчас это действие выполнить нельзя")
#           error.setIcon(QMessageBox.setIcon(Warning))
            error.setIcon(QMessageBox.Warning)
            error.setStandardButtons(
#               QMessageBox.StandardButton.Ok  | QMessageBox.StandardButton.Cancel
                QMessageBox.StandardButtons.Ok | QMessageBox.StandardButtons.Cancel
            )
            error.exec_()

    ...
```

Comment: ничего не изменилось

Comment: @Nikolay для тестирования, в методе `def results(self):` - уберите все и оставьте только то что я вам предложил. Приложение запустите в консоле/терминале/CMD и расскажите что у вас получилось.

Comment: @Nikolay что не так?